# Get the sum of a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the value of the cards dealt to a user. Can anyone give me a hand with what I can do? Thanks

```
import random
from random import shuffle

# Define the deck
def deck1():
    hand = []
    deck = {"Two": 2, "Three": 3, "Four": 4, "Five": 5, "Six": 6, "Seven": 7, "Eight": 8, 
            "Nine": 9, "Ten": 10, "Jack": 11, "Queen": 12, "King": 13, "Ace": 14}
    keys = list(deck.keys())
    random.shuffle(keys)
    shuffled = keys.pop()
    hand.append(shuffled)
    return hand

Create the user hand

userhand = []
for i in range(2):
    userhand.append(deck1())
print(userhand)

# Get the sum of the user hand
print(sum(userhand))
```

Comment: what do you get with `print(userhand)` ?

Comment: if `userhand` keeps two lists with numbers  then you should use `sum(userhand[0])` and `sum(userhand[1])`

Comment: if `deck1()` returns one card then you could do `return shuffled`. BTW: you could keep `deck = {...}` outside function - this directory can be needed in ohter functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need `dect = {...}` outside function because it is needed to sum cards

I assume `userhand` keeps two players

```
for player in userhand:
    print(sum(deck[cardname] for cardname in player))
```

or longer but simpler for beginner

```
for player in userhand:
    result = 0
    for cardname in player:
        result += deck[cardname]
    print(result)
```

If `userhand` keep only one player then you can nested `sum()`

```
print( sum(sum(deck[cardname] for cardname in hand) for hand in userhand) )
```

or longer but simpler for beginner

```
total_result = 0

for hand in userhand:
    result = 0
    for cardname in hand:
        result += deck[cardname]
    total_result += result    

print(total_result)
```

Or you could use `return shuffled` in `deck1()` because it returns only one card and there is no need to return it as list. It will create simpler data in `userhand` and it will need simpler code to sum it.

---

Minimal working code

```
import random
from random import shuffle

deck = {"Two": 2, "Three": 3, "Four": 4, "Five": 5, "Six": 6, "Seven": 7, "Eight": 8, 
        "Nine": 9, "Ten": 10, "Jack": 11, "Queen": 12, "King": 13, "Ace": 14}

# Define the deck
def deck1():
    hand = []
    keys = list(deck.keys())
    random.shuffle(keys)
    shuffled = keys.pop()
    hand.append(shuffled)
    return hand

userhand = []
for i in range(2):
    userhand.append(deck1())
print(userhand)

# Get the sum of the user hand
for player in userhand:
    print(sum(deck[cardname] for cardname in player))

for player in userhand:
    result = 0
    for cardname in player:
        result += deck[cardname]
    print(result)

print( sum(sum(deck[cardname] for cardname in hand) for hand in userhand) )


total_result = 0
for hand in userhand:
    result = 0
    for cardname in hand:
        result += deck[cardname]
    total_result += result    
print(total_result)
```